# how to disable gwt.material.design.client.ui.MaterialLink on specific situation?

Tags: gwt, material-design, gwt-material-design

I have this problem, I prepare a page with GWT, with the Materialink disabled.

my Java view:

```
 @UiField
 MaterialLink exportLink;
```

my view.xml:

```
 <m:MaterialLink ui:field="exportLink" text="Esporta Report" addStyleNames="btn" target="_blank"  float="RIGHT" enabled="false"/>
```

The button is disabled and the click not work (GOOD).

if the user complete the Form, I will enable it.

```
   exportLink.setHref(updatedUrl());
    exportLink.setEnabled(true);
```

and work perfert.

When I try to disable it becouse the user put a wrong value.

```
exportLink.setHref(null);
            exportLink.setEnabled(false);
```

the button looks ok but is possible to click it.
Any suggest?

Comment: I committed the fixed GMD https://github.com/GwtMaterialDesign/gwt-material/issues/787. Feel free to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
public class MyMaterialLink extends MaterialLink {

   @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        super.setEnabled(enabled);
        if(!enabled){
            if (getElement().getAttribute("href") != null) {//per prevenire doppi disabled che cancellano l'href-disabled
                getElement().setAttribute("data-href-disabled", getElement().getAttribute("href"));
                getElement().removeAttribute("href");
            }
        }else {
            getElement().setAttribute("href",getElement().getAttribute("data-href-disabled"));
            getElement().removeAttribute("data-href-disabled");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setHref(String href) {

        if(!isEnabled()){
            getElement().setAttribute("data-href-disabled",href);
        }else {
            super.setHref(href);
        }
    }
```